# setMicrophoneMute and setSpeakerPhoneOn not working in android audio call only (react-native)

Tags: react-native, webrtc

I have integrated voip call in react-native using react-native-webtrtc and in-call-manager (https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-incall-manager) for call management.Everything working fine with call. In-call-manager works fine for playing ringtone/busytone but also want user to have options to mute mic or turn on/off speaker phone while on call.

I have tried InCallManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true/false)   InCallManager.setMicrophoneMute(true/false) but no change occurred. Also I have opened issue on git but no response so hoping to get answer here

I expect if both function works fine then User is able to mute/unmute mic or turn on/off speakerphone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have dealt with this issue before you just have to add

```js
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

in the manifest file of your project.
Both InCallManager.setMicrophoneMute() and InCallManager.setSpeakerphoneOn() will work.

You are right though. This is not clearly mentioned on their Github page.

Comment: For me it's not working in iOS. Any suggestions?